# Spark job server for spark 1.6.0

Tags: spark-jobserver

Is there any specific Spark Job Server version matching with Spark 1.6.0 ?
As per the version information in https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver, I see SJS is available only for 1.6.1 not for 1.6.0.
Our CloudEra hosted Spark is running on 1.6.0

I deployed SJS by configuring the spark home to 1.6.1. When I submitted jobs, I see job ids are getting generated but I can't see the job result.
Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no SJS version tied to spark 1.6.0. But it should be easy for you to compile against 1.6.0. May be you could modify this https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/project/Versions.scala#L10 and try.

Comment: Thanks Noorul. SJS bin folder has server_deploy.sh and server_package.sh. If I'm compiling from the machine where spark is hosted (not planning to compile on Server A and then ssh to Server B), is it OK to user server_package.sh? It appears that this(server_package.sh) script too compiling the SJS like server_deploy.sh except ftping.

Comment: I think it should fine to run server_deploy.sh from the same machine as deploy server.